# Disable --output-directory in TeXpad

Tags: compiling, texpad

How can one disable the `--output-directory` from TeXpad compilation command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to a solution...
http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-os-x/what-if-the-package-minted-isnt-working-in-my-os-x-app

Comment: It seems that this page does no longer contain any information.